# Unable to get Yahoo OAuth 2 authorization

Tags: apache, oauth-2.0, yahoo-api, oltu

I am doing a poc project using Apache Oltu to authorize a Yahoo user using OAuth 2 spec. Following is the url that I am redirecting to. I get one of the 2 errors mentioned below. I see that many people come across this issue but I am not able to narrow down to what is causing the error. I have tried multiple trial and error values but it doesnt seem to get through. Can anyone help me with inputs? Appreciate your time.

Url:
https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth?response_type=code&client_secret=*sending correct value here*&redirect_uri=devvm03.ia.wd.org&client_id=*sending correct value here*

Errors:
Oops. Yahoo is unable to process your request.
We recommend that you contact the owner of the application or web site to resolve this issue. [95022]

Oops. Yahoo is unable to process your request.
We recommend that you contact the owner of the application or web site to resolve this issue. [95036]

Application Details:
Application URL:http://devvm03.ia.wd.org/dashboard
Callback Domain:devvm03.ia.wd.org

Answer (score 1):

You must provide a valid URL, starting with `http://` or `https://` in the `redirect_uri` value. If not done correctly you'll get the `95036` error. You also have to make sure the `client_id` value is correct and that you URL-encode the that value or else it will produce the `95022` error. You must **not** provide the `client_secret` parameter in the authorization request.

Comment: Thank you for the response Hans Z. I have corrected the redirect uri to point to the correct url my application uses. So I am not getting the 95036 error now. But I am continuing to get the 95022 error and I have double checked the client id. I am encoding it and I have removed the client secret from the query params.

Comment: Z Thank you for the response Hans Z. The issue was that I had not selected the right scope in the API settings. Once that was corrected, it worked. Thank you for explaining the error codes and about encoding and client secret. It was very helpful and I have made those changes.