# Yahoo OAuth2 Error 95022

Tags: yahoo

When trying to get a request token for an app, it gets the error:

> Oops. Yahoo is unable to process your request. We recommend that you
>   contact the owner of the application or web site to resolve this
>   issue. [95022] Close

This is the code raising the error:

```
var main = angular.module("main", ["ngRoute"]);

main.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
        controller: 'loginController'
    })
});

main.controller("loginController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.login = function () {
        var clientID =    "[redacted]";
        window.location.href =    "https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth?client_id=" + clientID + "&redirect_uri=http://www.acleanpairofshorts.com&response_type=token&language=en-us";
    };
});
```

Comment: Might be a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27933059/unable-to-get-yahoo-oauth-2-authorization)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to URL-encode the value of the `redirect_uri` parameter or else the arguments following that will be interpreted as part of that instead of the actual URL.